# Check if point is within a footnote

Tags: org-mode

How should we check if point is within a footnote?

`(looking-at org-footnote-re)` returns `t` only when point is *before* a footnote, but not when it is anywhere else *within* the footnote.

[image]

[image]

Comment: `org-footnote-at-reference-p`?

Comment: Please don't use tag `elisp` unless it's a question about the language itself, compared with other Lisp dialects.

Comment: @Dan: you should make your comment into an answer. I believe it's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `org-footnote-at-reference-p` indicates when you are
in a footnote.  Here's the docstring:

```
Is the cursor at a footnote reference?

If so, return a list containing its label, beginning and ending
positions, and the definition, when inlined.
```

I found this function by using `M-x apropos` with the pattern
"org footnote" and browsed the results to find the likely function.